# how do you cacculate avg of a list

Tags: python

I have a list called slopes and trying to calculate the overall avg values in the list like this:

```
 over_all_slope=float(sum(slopes))/float(len(slopes))
```

I get this error:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Looks like in my slopes list there values like None, now could I calculate the avg not including None values in the forumula?

Any ideas?

Comment: Does slopes contain non-number values?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, its all numeric.

Comment: Can you please put it in the post.

Comment: Use `print slopes` to see what is in the variable `slopes`.  My guess is it has `None` values in it.

Comment: @user1471980, it's not, it contains NoneType.

Comment: @ForceBru, Sorry, I do see values like None, how could I remove them?

Comment: I knew it @user1471980. Try my answer below.

Comment: @user1471980, `new_list=[]; for x in slopes: if x is not None: new_list.append(x);` and then sum values of `new_list`

Comment: @ForceBru Why not a list comprehension? It's much easier.

Comment: @ForceBru, I got it by doing slopes=filter(None,slopes), I really dont get the down voting. Trying to learn Python, what's wrong with asking questions?

Comment: Thank you all for the all down votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will filter out the None from the Slopes list.

```
slopes=filter(None,slopes)
```

Comment: Glad to see your solution! Because of list comprehension and generator expression, functional constructs (like `filter`) are not so common anymore. Yet I prefer them.

Comment: So you marked yourself as answer? How did you do that?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, filter seems to be a simple implementation and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

This is accurate code with precise type casting allowing for more accuracy. I really like it and it demonstrates a good understanding of math as well. But the truth is, the problem lies within the content of your list.

```
# create a list of slopes without None values

new = [i for i in slopes if not i is None]
avg = float(sum(new)) / float(len(new))
```

Comment: I prefer the equivalent `new = [i for i in slopes if i is not None]`. I find it more readable,

Comment: That improper order, but will yield the same results.

Comment: What do you mean? What order is improper?